# How to cleanup threadlocals after response written?

Tags: grails, thread-local

I have a Grails application that uses ThreadLocal.

Currently ThreadLocal populating and clearing is handled by a filter (**before**: populates, **after**: clears).

The problem is that the filter's **after**-call is run before template is rendered so my needful variables are all nulls prematurely. **Is there some simple way to trigger the clearing of ThreadLocals after the response is fully written?**

One approach would be to clear the ThreadLocal before populating it, thus leaving all the work for filter's **before**-call. But I don't like the idea of leaving the ThreadLocal "carrying" the vars after they're no longer used for anything so something else is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`after` is called after the controller action finishes - you want the cleanup to be in `afterView` which is called after the view is rendered.

Comment: Unfortunately `afterView` is still called before any layouts are rendered, meaning if you clean up your threadLocal in `afterView` it will not be available inside a layout.